# SharePoint/PnP getFileByServerRelativeURL - works in workbench, doesn't after deploy

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I am working on webpart that uses json from file in site's library.
Site: WebPart
Site -> Library -> file.json

I used PnP to download the file like this:

```
    pnp.sp.web.getFileByServerRelativePath(this.props.context.pageContext.site.serverRelativeUrl + "/AppRegister/apps.json").
getText().then((text: string)  => {
  this.setState({result: this.parseJSONtoHTML(text)});
});
```

And it worked in workbench, but on actual site I get 404.
There is some difference in generated request:
Local -

> https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/YYY/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/YYY/AppRegister/apps.json')/$value

Deployed:

> https://XXX.sharepoint.com/sites/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/YYY/AppRegister/apps.json')/$value

So I believe this is because deployed webpart takes only "sites" without specific site, but I have no idea how to change it. 
Or maybe there is better way to download file from sharepoint library in react?

Comment: This approach looks generally correct, but the server-relative url discrepancy in the sp client is odd. Did you make sure to configure the sp client, e.g. `pnp.sp.setup({ spfxContext: this.props.context })` ([reference](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/docs/#getting-started-sharepoint-framework) using @pnp/sp, but the principle should be the same)? Also, where is the web part deployed?

Comment: Turns out I did not. Such a stupid mistake to waste so much time on. Thanks a lot!